# Easy Delphi XE6 FireMonkey Controls TListBox and TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey, tstringgrid, tlistbox

How does one get columns into a FireMonkey TListBox and then get the values out of the columns for the rows a TListBox. I am using this approach:

vListRow := 'Col1Stuff' + '^I' + 'Col2Stuff';

This is NOT giving me Col1Stuff in the 1st column and Col2Stuff in the 2nd Column.

I tried the TStringGrid Firemonkey control as an alternative, but the following approach is not working either:

vStringGrid.Cells[0,1] := 'Hi';
vStringGrid.Cells[0,2] := 'There';

This puts nothing in the TStringGrid.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `TListBox`, use a tab character (#9):

```
ListBox1.Items.Add('Column A' + #9 + 'Column B');
```

To get the values out, you'd have to parse them back out, using the tab character as the delimiter (separator). It's usually more efficient and readable to use the ItemIndex instead, however.

Since you're doing direct concatenation, you can even omit the '+' (but you have to also remove the leading and trailing space:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add('Column A'#9'Column B');
```

For the `TStringGrid`, use the Items Editor to add two `TStringColumns` to the grid. You can then access the `Cells` property to read/write values - note that `Cells` are referenced by [column, row] values:

```
StringGrid1.Cells[0, 1] := 'Column A';   // Column 0, Row 1
StringGrid1.Cells[1, 1] := 'Column B';   // Column 1, Row 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. I discovered my error with the TStringGrid independently. I did not know about the tab character for the TListBox, but I don't want to have to use string operations to retrieve the values of the columns in TListBox and so the TStringGrid is the better option.